Which algebraic structure characterizes the set of non-trivial qudratic residues in a finite field?
I understand this question may be too naive to ask, but I am unable to figure it out.
Suppose, $\mathbb{QR^*}$ denotes the set of all quadratic residues in a finite field except the identity element $1$. So, what should I call the algebraic structure $\mathbb{QR^*}$ with field multiplication? Since, it does not have the identity element $1$ it can not be called a monoid, so neither a group. But calling it a semi-group also incorrect as the product of two elements $\mathbb{QR^*}$ may be equal to $1$, so $\mathbb{QR^*}$ is not closed under field multiplication. Therefore, what should be the correct characterization of this struccture?

Why do you want to remove $1$? If you include it, the quadratic residues have a group structure (if the size of the field is odd, it is the index 2 subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$ and otherwise it's the full group of units). By the way, this question is probably more appropriate on math.SE.

The reason is that the underlying application faces an issue with $1$. Yes, the size of the field is odd.

In general, if you take a group, and remove the identity element, you get something that (in my humble opinion) isn't very interesting, so has probably never been given a name.

Thank you for this explanation.
